# "Press any key to continue..." message shown in "Start Without Debugging" mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, console-application

I created a blank C# console application in Visual Studio as shown below:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Solution
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the default `Start Debugging` option by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> then the program runs normally as expected. I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and program ends.

But when I use `Start Without Debugging` option by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> it shows me an extra message on console after I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

> Press any key to continue...

[image]

Then I've to press an additional key on the keyboard to terminate the program. From where is this magical message coming and why it is shown only in `Start Without Debugging` option?

**Note**:Post-build event command line of the project is completely empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is simply how visual studio runs console programs not in debug mode. As far as I am aware it can not be controlled. Since it shows that it is actually a cmd.exe instance and not just a console window I assume VS uses the /K flag on the command line (I had thought it used a batch file but now see there is no need for that).

It is done for the typical case where a console program runs and simply exits, without that message such a program would not give any chance to see the output.

Comment: Happens to me in debug mode too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to validate the information shared by @SoronelHaetir in his answer. I'm detailing out the same here with the help of some screenshots which will complement the information in his post and help you understand the same better:

1. When I run the application using the default `Start Debugging` option by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>, we can see the executable of the application getting launched in task manager:

[image]

When I right click on the task and choose `Go To Process` option from context menu, I'm taken to a process on the process tab having image name `ConsoleApp1.exe *32` as shown below. This makes perfect sense.

[image]

2. Now when I run the application using `Start Without Debugging` option by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, we **do not** see the executable of the application getting launched in task manager. In fact we see `cmd.exe` being launched as shown below:

[image]

Now, when I right click on the `cmd.exe` task and choose `Go To Process` option from context menu, I'm taken to a process on the process tab having an image name `cmd.exe *32` as shown below. But there is more to it. You also see `ConsoleApp1.exe *32` running in the process tab which was not visible in `Applications` tab.

[image]

So this is how all the dots get connected that in `Start Without Debugging` mode Visual Studio in fact launches a `cmd.exe` instance which in turn launches our application `ConsoleApp1.exe`.

The moment I press enter, `ConsoleApp1.exe` process gets terminated but `cmd.exe` process continue to live on until I press another key as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Yes, and the `cmd.exe` which "wraps" your executable is launched like this: `"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c ""[your.exe]"  & pause"`, which you can verify for yourself with a tool like Process Explorer, which can show you the command-line a program was launched with. In cmd, a single ampersand unconditionally chains two commands together on a single command-line.